# Sysdig doesn’t record events inside Kubernetes pods

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

I use Microk8s kubectl. I tried to record events inside a pod (named e.g., mypod) using sysdig by setting a filter k8s.pod.name=mypod (specifically through `$sysdig k8s.pod.name=mypod`). But sysdig does not show any logged event. For example, it doesn't show any system call when I attempt to `$cat /etc/passwd` of the container inside the pod.

p.s. I can get the events inside docker containers (not in pods) using sysdig while setting the filter container.name=mycontainer.

I would appreciate any possible explanation/solution about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you need to connect to the k8s api server, here is a description from the man page:

-k, --k8s-api
Enable Kubernetes support by connecting to the API server
specified as argument.  E.g.
"http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:8080".  The API server can
also be specified via the environment variable SYSDIG_K8S_API.

Once you connect to the k8s api that filter will work.

Comment: Thank you so much!